# Does ETS smoothing model work for more than one year forecast in R?

Tags: r, forecasting, ets

I am currently using ets() to forecast future values based on historic time series data in R. I used forecast() function to predict next 24 data points. However, the output gives same numbers for the first 12 and the last 12 data points. For example, the forecast-ed value of May 2012 is replicated in May 2013.

Following Data passed:

> ```
> 2005.04.30    87.6
> 2005.05.31    95.4
> 2005.06.30    97.7
> 2005.07.31    101.3
> 2005.08.31    100.6
> 2005.09.30    97
> 2005.10.31    91.1
> 2005.11.30    92.1
> 2005.12.31    112
> 2006.01.31    113.9
> 2006.02.28    103.9
> 2006.03.31    115.1
> 2006.04.30    100
> 2006.05.31    107.5
> 2006.06.30    110
> 2006.07.31    114.2
> 2006.08.31    109.4
> 2006.09.30    108.9
> 2006.10.31    114.6
> 2006.11.30    113
> 2006.12.31    116.5
> 2007.01.31    120.2
> 2007.02.28    112.6
> 2007.03.31    124.1
> 2007.04.30    113.4
> 2007.05.31    121
> 2007.06.30    117.9
> 2007.07.31    118.4
> 2007.08.31    119.5
> 2007.09.30    113.5
> 2007.10.31    117.8
> 2007.11.30    118.2
> 2007.12.31    120.6
> 2008.01.31    126.1
> 2008.02.29    121.2
> 2008.03.31    127.4
> 2008.04.30    119.5
> 2008.05.31    121.5
> 2008.06.30    125.7
> 2008.07.31    131.4
> 2008.08.31    123.5
> 2008.09.30    122.8
> 2008.10.31    125.3
> 2008.11.30    119.4
> 2008.12.31    121.2
> 2009.01.31    123.7
> 2009.02.28    118.1
> 2009.03.31    128.7
> 2009.04.30    112.2
> 2009.05.31    115.4
> 2009.06.30    119.8
> 2009.07.31    117.4
> 2009.08.31    127.8
> 2009.09.30    124.4
> 2009.10.31    131
> 2009.11.30    118.9
> 2009.12.31    124
> 2010.01.31    127.4
> 2010.02.28    116.3
> 2010.03.31    126.4
> 2010.04.30    115.7
> 2010.05.31    117.7
> 2010.06.30    122.4
> 2010.07.31    121.9
> 2010.08.31    116.7
> 2010.09.30    110.9
> 2010.10.31    120.7
> 2010.11.30    116.7
> 2010.12.31    131.2
> 2011.01.31    137.1
> 2011.02.28    118.7
> 2011.03.31    128.5
> 2011.04.30    123.5
> 2011.05.31    126.1
> 2011.06.30    127.7
> 2011.07.31    125.3
> 2011.08.31    126.7
> 2011.09.30    114
> 2011.10.31    116.5
> 2011.11.30    128
> 2011.12.31    130.6
> ```

Code:

```
ETSfit <- ets(data.ts)
data.ets <- forecast(ETSfit, level=70, h=24)
```

Output:

> ```
>           Point Forecast    Lo 70    Hi 70
>  Jan 2012       133.6314 129.3483 137.9145
>  Feb 2012       123.5998 118.7221 128.4775
>  Mar 2012       133.1607 127.7534 138.5681
>  Apr 2012       121.0877 115.1982 126.9773
>  May 2012       125.4991 119.1639 131.8342
>  Jun 2012       127.5913 120.8399 134.3427
>  Jul 2012       128.4923 121.3489 135.6358
>  Aug 2012       127.2225 119.7074 134.7376
>  Sep 2012       122.1938 114.3247 130.0630
>  Oct 2012       125.5382 117.3302 133.7462
>  Nov 2012       123.3347 114.8012 131.8682
>  Dec 2012       129.9972 121.1503 138.8441
>  Jan 2013       133.6314 124.4818 142.7810
>  Feb 2013       123.5998 114.1572 133.0424
>  Mar 2013       133.1607 123.4340 142.8875
>  Apr 2013       121.0877 111.0849 131.0906
>  May 2013       125.4991 115.2275 135.7706
>  Jun 2013       127.5913 117.0579 138.1246
>  Jul 2013       128.4923 117.7035 139.2812
>  Aug 2013       127.2225 116.1841 138.2609
>  Sep 2013       122.1938 110.9114 133.4763
>  Oct 2013       125.5382 114.0169 137.0595
>  Nov 2013       123.3347 111.5793 135.0901
>  Dec 2013       129.9972 118.0123 141.9821
> ```

Kindly help.

Comment: Please help us help you by providing us with a reproducible example (i.e. code and example data), see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example for details.

Comment: hi..i have given the data passed to the function, the code as well as the output

Answer (score 0):

Look at the fitted model:

```
ETS(A,N,A) 

Call:
 ets(y = x) 

  Smoothing parameters:
    alpha = 0.5449 
    gamma = 1e-04 

  Initial states:
    l = 95.8994 
    s=6.3817 -3.1792 6.8525 3.218 -3.4445 -1.2408
           -4.5852 0.4434 1.7133 0.8123 -1.28 -5.6914

  sigma:  4.1325

     AIC     AICc      BIC 
613.8103 620.1740 647.3326
```

So there is no trend selected. Therefore the forecasts will have only seasonal pattern and no trend, which is exactly what you've got.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out. Can you please suggest which model to go for in such a case?

Comment: Use the model ets gives you. If there's no trend in the data, you presumably don't want trend in the forecasts either.